# Remove all occurrences of an integer from an int array

Tags: java, arrays

How can I remove all occurrences of an integer, say, 17 in this example from a given array in java?
I tried setting entries to (Integer) null though it doesn't work.

Input array: `[0,6,0,17,1,9,17,8,4]`

Output array: `[0,6,0,1,9,8,4]`

```
for(int i =0;i<ansa.length;i++){
if(ansa[i]==17)
      {
          ansa[i]=(Integer)null;
      }
}
```

This results in

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: I'm sure that a lot of answers are on the way.

Comment: please share code, you've tried so far.

Comment: @devnull you comment has really blocked `a lot of answer on the way`.

Comment: Why not use ArrayList?

Comment: Did you declare your array as `int[]`, or as `Integer[]`?

Comment: How to accept answers?

Comment: klick on the tick below the votes of an answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
int[] array = { 0,6,0,17,1,9,17,8,4 };
int[] filtered = Arrays.stream(array).filter(i -> i != 17).toArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(filtered));
```

:-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

```
Integer[] array ={0,6,0,17,1,9,17,8,4};
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>( Arrays.asList(array ));  
list.removeAll(Arrays.asList(17 ));
array =list.toArray(new Integer[0]);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

Answer (score 1):

> I tried setting entries to (Integer) null though it doesn't work.

Of course it doesn't, because the size of the array isn't changed. In order to do this, some of the defined java collections (in particular, the `ArrayList` and `Iterator` classes) can provide you of a better approach.

In pseudocode:

```
Turn array into a List
Iterate over its elements
    If the element is the given number
        Remove it
Return the List as an Array
```

You can fill in the blanks, just remember that you can't actually *remove* an element from an array, because its size is static.

*Note: I'm going for the educational approach.*

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work - although I suspect people will post better/more efficient solutions.

```
public void test() {
  int[] before = new int[] {0,6,0,17,1,9,17,8,4};
  int[] after = remove(before, 17);
  System.out.println("Before: "+Arrays.toString(before));
  System.out.println("Aftre: "+Arrays.toString(after));
}

private int[] remove(int[] before, int remove) {
  // Work out how long it must be.
  int keep = 0;
  for ( int i = 0; i < before.length; i++ ) {
    if(before[i] != remove) {
      keep += 1;
    }
  }
  // Make the new one
  int[] after = new int[keep];
  // Fill it in.
  for ( int i = 0, j = 0; i < before.length; i++ ) {
    if(before[i] != remove) {
      after[j++] = before[i];
    }
  }
  return after;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats one possible solution:

```
    int[] array1 = new int[]{0,6,0,17,1,9,17,8,4};
    ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    boolean flag = true;

    for(int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < array1.length; j++) {
            if(array1[i]==array1[j]&&i!=j) {
                flag = false;
            }
        }
        if(flag) {
            result.add(array1[i]);
        }
        else{
            flag = true;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, if you don't want to use an ArrayList, you will have to count how many 17 are in the array and create a new one with ansa.length-count fields

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove items from an array you are currently using a for loop to cycle through. At the moment you are getting to the end of your array and looking for the next value even though you deleted it. The array length indicator (ansa.length) does not auto update as you are thinking.

You should use List and an iterator to cycle through the list.
You can use then use the .remove function

Answer (score 0):

You are almost done!!

```
    Integer[] ansa = new Integer[] { 0, 6, 0, 17, 1, 9, 17, 8, 4 };
    for (int i = 0; i < ansa.length; i++) {
        if (ansa[i] == 17) {
            ansa[i] = (Integer) null;
        }
    }

    for (Integer integer : ansa) {
        System.out.print(integer+","); //0,6,0,null,1,9,null,8,4,
    }
```

You are facing issue, Because you declared primitive I guess like,

```
int[] ansa = new int[] // Primitive
```

Comment: This would leave NULL values in the OPs array. OP requested output with no NULL values. However originally question suggested otherwise.

Comment: @Intern87 `I tried setting entries to (Integer) null though it doesn't work.`